# R markdown alignment with Latex equations

Tags: latex, markdown, r-markdown

I am trying to produce a PDF document with R markdown which includes some equations and r code. I am trying to align sub-items in an un-ordered list which appear after the equations.

Below is the code. I want the words **Prediction** and **Inference** to start as new sub items.

````
---
title: "Test"
author: "Author"
date: "21 April 2018"
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

* Main Point
    + **Prediction** - Some text here

$$
\hat{Y}=\hat{f(X)}+\epsilon   ...............     (2.2)
$$
$$
E( Y - \hat{Y} )^2 
= E[f(X) + \epsilon - \hat{f(X)}]^2 
=[f(X) - \hat{f(X)}]^2+Var(\epsilon)     .........  (2.3) 
$$
    + **Inference** - Some text here
````

[image: Output PDF]

No matter what spacing I try, nothing seems to be working. Currently, after the "Main Point", I have given two tabs before the "+" before "Prediction". This works absolutely fine and produces the sub item of the "Main Point". However, after the two equations when I try the same formatting that I did for the first sub-item, it does not work at all and produces the alignment as shown in the picture.

Comment: Further to my answer, you will also want to check out the bookdown package, which is an extension of rmarkdown. It allows numbering of equations: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Markdown has a few rules to make sublists work. Most importantly in your case, sub-items only work if there is a parent item to it. As Stackoverflow uses the same syntax, we can show the examples inline. For example:

```
1. Item
2. Item
   * Mixed
   * Mixed
```

1. Item
2. Item

   - Mixed
   - Mixed

In your case, you have put some none list items between the sub-items, as follows:

```
1. Item
2. Item
   * Mixed

Some Text    
   * Mixed
```

1. Item
2. Item

   - Mixed

Some Text
   * Mixed

As you can see, the list has been broken and is not recognised as an item.

### Workaround

If you are only using PDF output, you are able to use LaTeX commands to achieve custom styling. In your case, you can use the `hspace` command to add a separation:

````
---
output: pdf_document
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

* Main Point


\hspace{1cm} + **Prediction** - Some text here

$$
\hat{Y}=\hat{f(X)}+\epsilon   ...............     (2.2)
$$
$$
E( Y - \hat{Y} )^2 
= E[f(X) + \epsilon - \hat{f(X)}]^2 
=[f(X) - \hat{f(X)}]^2+Var(\epsilon)     .........  (2.3) 
$$
\hspace{1cm} + **Inference** - Some text here
````

[image]